# Dynamically adding a custom view to RemoteViews

Tags: android-widget

Could any help me to do this? My code is like:

```
 public CustomClass extends View {

//uses ondraw() to do something

}
```

For displaying my custom view on the home screen I created a class to extend Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class customAppWidgetProvider extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action)) {
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.main);

           //Here I want to create my custom view class object and I want to add this view to linear layout in main.xml

              CustomClass object = new CustomClass(context) ;
              LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context) ;
              layout.setLayoutParameters(new LayoutParameters(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
              layout.addView(object);

            views.addview(R.id.linearlayout, (ViewGroup) layout) ;
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.analog_appwidget,
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                        new Intent(context, AlarmClock.class),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

            int[] appWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

            AppWidgetManager gm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            gm.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
        }
    }
}
```

But adding `ViewGroup` to RemoteView reference is not working... The main.xml layout above contains only LinearLayout. I want to add a custom view object to it. But after running this nothing shows on screen...

Please help me to do this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8):

It's not possible to add a custom `View` to an app widget.  See [the "Creating the App Widget Layout" section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) of the App Widgets Dev Guide for what `View` types are allowed.

Android 3.0 adds support for some views to display collections.  See the "Using App Widgets with Collections" section for details.

Otherwise, to dynamically add an allowed `View` to an App Widget, after inflating the `RemoteViews` and getting a reference to it, you can use its `addView(View)` method, or the `addView(View)` method on any of the `View` objects already in the `RemoteViews`.